# Emails sent using GMAIL Send API are shown in sent but not in the inbox thread

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-api, gmail-api, google-api-ruby-client

I am using Gmail's Ruby API to reply to a message.
My outgoing message has the same subject, references, in-reply-to headers.
But my sent message is not shown in the inbox as a part of the existing thread.

Here is how my code looks like:

```
client = Google::Auth::ClientId.from_file(ENV["CLIENT_SECRETS_PATH"])

service = Google::Apis::GmailV1::GmailService.new
service.client_options.application_name = ENV["APPLICATION_NAME"]
scope = []
scope << 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify'
service.authorization = Google::Auth::UserRefreshCredentials.new(token_credential_uri: 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token',
                                                                      client_id: client.id,
                                                                      client_secret: client.secret,
                                                                      refresh_token: data["refresh_token"],
                                                                      scope: scope)
m = MIME::Mail.new
m.to=data["to"]
m.from=data["from"]
m.subject=data["subject"]
m.body= Text.new(data["body"], 'html')
**m.in_reply_to=data["reply_to"]** # This is the Message-ID of the message I want to reply to.
**m.references=data["reply_to"]**  # This is the Message-ID of the message I want to reply to.

message_object = Google::Apis::GmailV1::Message.new(raw:m.to_s)                 
response = service.send_user_message("me", message_object)
```

Comment: Added the code.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/threads  you need to add the thread id.

Comment: Thanks. But is it possible to get the google message id using the Message-Id header, as I don't know the message_id of the message I am replying to.